# How to use/code stored procedure to stop MYSQL currently running task?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, business-process-management, appian

Here is my node, which sometimes freezes by the last INSERT command:

[image]

This process sometimes will freeze because the functionality for this node is to truncate the table. But sometimes the previous inserting command is not finished and the truncate is triggered, which will cause this node freeze for 2 hours to complete (originally should be 2 seconds to finish).

So my solution is to set up a timer condition if this node take too long then run the Stored procedure stop all `MySQL` current database tasks (the inserting Action which insert data to this table).

What stored procedure can do this work?

Comment: You had moved in a wrong direction and finally looking for a solution to patch up. Better to reverse the whole and start afresh by re-designing so that you do not need to truncate often. Also, it is unexpected to truncate when insertion is happening. 2 seconds to 2 hours !!! As I mentioned...better to re-design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the previous node that is doing the insert, configured to run multiple instances? If it is then it is probably configured to "Move on when: Each time an instance finishes". If that is the case then you can configure the previous node to "Move on when: All instances are done".